# Problem with using a non-abstract type as a generic type in a method

Tags: c#

I have this code that I am trying to use in my application:

```
public partial class DataManager 
{

    public DataManager()
    {
        db2 = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB2>().GetConnection();
    }

    T RunQuery<T>(string qry)
    {
        lock (l)
        {
            try
            {
                T data = db2.Query<T>(qry);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.WriteLine(qry);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

However the code is showing this error:

> Error CS0310: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public
>   parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Query(string, params
>   object[])'

Can anyone give me advice on what this means and possibly how I can solve the problem.

Comment: Add the constraint `where T : new()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a Generic Constraint to satisfy the requirement and let the compiler know that the type passed in will always have a parameterless constructor, add `where T: new()` to the method definition. Read more on generic constraints here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

```
public partial class DataManager 
{
    public DataManager()
    {
        db2 = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB2>().GetConnection();
    }

    List<T> RunQuery<T>(string qry) where T: new()
    {
        lock (l)
        {
            try
            {
                List<T> data = db2.Query<T>(qry);
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.WriteLine(qry);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me a slightly different message: Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'T'

Comment: @Alan2 - What's the return type of `SQLiteConnection.Query`? It sounds like it's `List<T>` so you need `List<T> data = db2.Query<T>(qry)` and to change the return type of your `RunQuery` function to `List<T>`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect on @Lee's statement. If T is your data type and you're querying a set, you should not tell your `RunQuery` to return `List<T>`, just `<T>` and the method return type should instead be `List<T>`. Otherwise nothing stops a developer from coming along and breaking the integration by specifying `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: yes it's a List<T>  actually I didn't yet use the method.  The error comes up with the method declaration.  Is that something to do with the way you do the new() ?